# Xcode: Embed Framework in React Native Module without modifying application project

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am developing a React Native Module that includes our Framework  `AntaviSense`.
I am able to include the framework in the main project and by `embed framework` in the Project Settings, everything works fine.

React Native Module

[image: React Native Module]

Adding to the main project works

[image: Adding to main project works]

My question though is: can I avoid changing the main project, and just include it in the React Native Module project (which is a subproject)? I tried various directories in `React-Module/Build Phases/Copy Files` without luck. This would make the inclusion into other projects much easier.

Comment: Did you try in your "React Native Module" target to include `AntaviSense` framework in "Embedded Binaries"?

Comment: A library doesn't have an option to include framework in embedded binaries as it's not a "binary".

Comment: Having the same exact problem, I've tried to solve it following https://medium.com/@jverhoeven/react-native-modules-frameworks-eb59532fd446 but without success. @ulf did you manage to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

[node-xcode](https://github.com/apache/cordova-node-xcode) could be an option, it enables you to parse an modify XCode projects, I am not a React developer but you could create a node-script which modifies the project and adds the framework when you add the module (in cordova this would be a hook, maybe there is something similar in React).